# Is there a more javascript way to handle zipping two arrays instead of using a for loop?

Tags: javascript

This code works as intended based on the problem I am supposed to solve. However, as I am new to JavaScript, I was curious if this is the proper way to handle zipping two arrays. I've already read a few examples using map which seem concise, but I am more curious if there is a generally agreed upon proper method in JavaScript to do this?

```
var faker = require("faker");

var products = Array.from({length:10}, () => faker.commerce.productName());
var prices = Array.from({length:10}, () => faker.commerce.price())

var strOut = "";
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
    strOut += `${products[i]} - ${prices[i]} \n`
}

console.log('====================\n'+
'WELCOME TO MY SHOP!\n'+
'====================\n'+
`${strOut}`);
```

Comment: You may have a reason for zipping, but the most common advice is _"Don't use parallel arrays."_ A single array that contains _objects_ such as `{ "product" : "some product", "price" : 5.99 }` is a better structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
const strOut = products.reduce(
  (result, product, index) => `${result} ${product} ${prices[index]}\n`,
  ''
);
```

2) [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) + [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
const strOut = products.map( 
   (product, index) => `${product} ${prices[index]}`
).join("\n");
```

second argument of `map`'s callback is the array index, you can use it for second array.